# Why the private key is not present for the certificate retrieved from the personal information exchange file?

Tags: cryptography

certificate data is retrieved from the personal information exchange using the following Crypto API's

```
hCertStore = PFXImportCertStore( &data, wszPassword, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE );
            if ( !hCertStore )
            {
                hResult = GetLastError();
                __leave;
            } // if

            pUsrCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(
                hCertStore,
                pUsrCertContext );
            if( !pUsrCertContext )
            {
                hResult = GetLastError( );
                __leave;
            } // if
```

The result of PFXImportCertStore is certificate + private key.
This certificate + private key is added to the store as

```
pUsrAuthCertContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
            pUsrCertContext->pbCertEncoded,
                pUsrCertContext->cbCertEncoded );
        if ( !pUsrAuthCertContext )
        {
            hResult = GetLastError();
            __leave;
        } // if
        //
        // Open the certificate store to add certificates to store
        //
        hUsrCertStore = CertOpenSystemStore(
            NULL,
            //L"TrustedPeople" 
            L"MY");
        if ( ! hUsrCertStore )
        {
            hResult =  GetLastError( );
            __leave;
        } // if
if ( ! CertAddCertificateContextToStore(
            hUsrCertStore,
            pUsrAuthCertContext ,
            CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING,
            0 ) )
        {
            hResult = GetLastError( );
            __leave;
        } // if
```

Now this certificate is added to the store but it is not having the private key with it. 
What is the flag that i have missed to specify for adding the certificate along with private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link from certificate to private key is not written in the certificate. It is an externally maintained properly. When you called `CertCreateCertificateContext()`, you just imported the certificate itself, not the link.

The link is a combination of two names (two strings): the name of the CSP, and the name of the key container within that CSP. When you called `PFXImportCertStore()`, Windows:

1. Imported the private key into a suitable CSP, with an appropriate container name.
2. Created a temporary certificate store.
3. Pushed the certificate into that store.
4. Added a link from that certificate in that store, to the private key as it was imported in the first step.

Your code pushed the certificate in the permanent store (your "My" store) but did not transport the link. You have to get the CSP and container names from the certificate in the temporary store, and set that information on the context returned by `CertCreateCertificateContext()`. This is done with [`CertGetCertificateContextProperty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CertSetCertificateContextProperty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using the `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID`  property. The relevant names (CSP and container name) and additional flags travel as a [`CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.